# disable webview scrolling gives -setscrollingEnabled no method found warning.but its working good?

Tags: xcode

I have been using this:

```
[[[WebView subviews] lastObject] setScrollingEnabled:NO];
```

Why is it giving a warning?
NO -setscrolling method found

Answer (score 0):

It raises a warning because this method isn't exposed and thus is considered as a private API call.
Leaving it like that will most certainly result on your app being rejected by Apple.

Here is a workaround that works and is currently on several apps in the store;

```
UIScrollView *lastScroll = (UIScrollView *)[[webView subviews] lastObject];
lastScroll.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

The same way you can customize some other behavior:

```
lastScroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
lastScroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
lastScroll.bounces = NO;
```